# Hibernate / JPA, Unique Constraint on column Per Associated entity (ex: each user cannot have duplicate entries but can be duplicates overall)

Tags: java, database, hibernate, validation, jpa

I have a situation that I thought would be straightforward and fairly common but am having trouble locating resources on how to accomplish this. Perhaps I am just using the wrong terminology to search for on this.

Basically, I have a situation where I have an two entities (pseudocode below):

```
@Entity:
User {

int id;

String username;

}



@Entity
Datarecord {

User user;

String recordEntry;
}
```

I want to make it so that there can only be one `DataRecord` entry per User with the same `recordEntry` value. So, there can be many entries in the database with the same `recordEntry` but each one must be associated with a different user. Could anyone point me to resources on this. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you need is a ManyToMany relationship between User and DataRecord. This will create a join table satisfying your criteria.

So while User table will have unique users and DataRecord table will have unique recordEntries, the join table will have records that map a user to multiple recordEntries. Correspondingly, a record entry will be mapped to multiple users.

```
user_recordentry_table

user  recordEntry
----  -----------
U1       R1
U1       R2
U1       R3
U2       R1
U2       R2
U2       R3
....
```

Comment: i would do it this way but the record entry would have other columns that differ between users, i know i can solve this with more tables but was hoping to find a way to keep it simpler with a constraint